# Python: How to remove \n from a list element 2D?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem, in a 2D list:

```
t = [['\n'], ['1', '1', '1', '1\n']]
```

I want to remove the `"\n"` from the nested lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip all strings in the nested lists:

```
t = [[s.strip() for s in nested] for nested in t]
```

This would remove *all* whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) from the start and end of each string.

Use `str.rstrip('\n')` if you need to be more precise:

```
t = [[s.rstrip('\n') for s in nested] for nested in t]
```

If you need to remove *empty* values too, you may have to filter twice:

```
t = [[s.rstrip('\n') for s in nested if not s.isspace()] for nested in t]
t = [nested for nested in t if nested]
```

where the first line only includes a stripped string if it contains more than just whitespace, and the second loop removes entirely empty lists. In Python 2, you could also use:

```
t = filter(None, nested)
```

for the latter line.

Comment: wow ... thank you very much for your answer ,,, is very help me .. :D,
i'm newbie in python :D